# FabricJS rotate around X Y axis

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Could anybody know how to rotate around X or Y axis of object in fabric.js and Animate it?
Like in CSS `transform: rotateY( 90deg );` or `transform: rotateX( 90deg );`

Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/uxable/YHeKX/ just for canvas Elemnts in fabricJS

Answer (score 0):

This is do-able, but I feel like you would need to make use heavily of matrix transformations.

http://fabricjs.com/matrix-transformation/ for a demo of the feature. There is even a link to an article about how they worked in Flash.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19163589/3538503 for an answer on how to perform matrix transformations.